# Name-based virtual hosts not working/allowed in Apache 2.4.9 on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, ipv6, osx-yosemite

After upgrading from Mavericks to Yosemite, my local MAMP environment stopped working. It was working perfectly on 10.9.

Specifically, the virtual hosts I have defined in `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf` no longer works. I just get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome when trying to access any of these hostnames, eg. `http://wp/` (I'll use that as an example here).

Weirdly, I don't get *anything* in the log-files, neither `/var/log/apache2/access_log` nor `/var/log/apache2/error_log`.

Here's my full `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"

Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module libexec/apache2/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module libexec/apache2/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module libexec/apache2/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module libexec/apache2/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache2/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module libexec/apache2/mod_echo.so
#LoadModule buffer_module libexec/apache2/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule data_module libexec/apache2/mod_data.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module libexec/apache2/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module libexec/apache2/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule reflector_module libexec/apache2/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule substitute_module libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module libexec/apache2/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module libexec/apache2/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module libexec/apache2/mod_xml2enc.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule ldap_module libexec/apache2/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
#LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
##LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module libexec/apache2/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule session_module libexec/apache2/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_plain.so
#LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule dialup_module libexec/apache2/mod_dialup.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User Cab
Group staff
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Files "rsrc">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>

ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"

LogLevel info

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

TraceEnable off

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

My `httpd-userdir.conf`

```
UserDir Sites
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
<IfModule bonjour_module>
       RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>
```

My `username.conf`

```
<Directory "/Users/Cab/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /Users/Cab/Sites/wp
  ServerName wp
  ServerAlias wp.*.xip.io
</VirtualHost>
```

(with a lot of `VirtualHosts` set up identically.)

`sudo apachectl -t` gives me:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using CabBook.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

and `sudo apachectl -S`:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using CabBook.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server wp (/private/etc/apache2/users/Cab.conf:8)
         port 80 namevhost wp (/private/etc/apache2/users/Cab.conf:8)
         [ ... edited for brevity ... ]
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="Cab" id=501
Group: name="staff" id=20
```

Going to `http://localhost` renders that `wp` hostname just fine (since it's the first defined in my `username.conf`, thus [the default](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).). But alas, `http://wp/` is just borked.
I suspect it's a permission issue, but cannot determine if any permissions are set up incorrectly.

My Sites dir:

```
drwxr-xr-x   20 Cab  staff      680 Oct 26 15:47 Sites
```

And `username.conf`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Cab   staff  2198 Oct 26 15:24 Cab.conf
```

Both the same as the user/group Apache is running under. I'm at a loss :(
Any help/pointers greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

So I discovered that it works if I set up the hostname with IPv6 in my `/etc/hosts`.
Like so

```
::1 wp
```

Which then enables me to see the site. Here's what I get in my apache access log:

```
::1 - - [28/Oct/2014:14:01:28 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20232
```

However, this doesn't fully solve my problem. I still can't access the site with something like xip.io, which I use for testing a local site on multiple devices (hence the `ServerAlias wp.*.xip.io` in username.conf).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:

```
::1 wp wp.*.xip.io
```

Or add xip.io to your resolv.conf file.

(Is that a literal '*' in your server alias - I'm surprised that works)

Comment: It seems odd that I would have to add `wp.*.xip.io` to my hosts file or resolv.conf, that hasn't been necessary on 10.9 or 10.8 — can you elaborate a bit on why that would be needed on 10.10?

(and yes, it's a literal asterisk (`*`) in my server alias :) Can't tell you why it works, but it does :P)

Thanks for taking your time to assist me!

Comment: I don't know of any changes in 10.10 that would mean you now need it when you didn't before. If you don't have the full name in your hosts file, then I would expect your browser to look for the name in DNS, and fail. If you add xip.io to your resolv.conf, then you don't need to add the domain suffix to your hosts, so 'wp' would automatically have the domain suffix added.